# Workbench Ansys Mesh Convergence study

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, meshing

Is it possible to perform a mesh study using Ansys?

So I want to change the mesh size, and show the effect of this on my solutions, any suggestions?

Comment: Run the same model with finer and finer mesh - plot the results.

Comment: Hi I’m stuck on how and what to plot?